# How to draw the axis with ContourPlot3D

Tags: graphics3d

I see ContourPlot3D doesn't show the X, Y, Z axis by default (i mean inside the graph), i tried adding ",Axis->True" to the call, but doesn't make effect.

How to do this?

Comment: Try `Boxed -> False` ... the axes are there by default

Comment: @belisarius Ok, that is not how i want to se the axis, i mean the axis centered in the graph... is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ContourPlot3D[
 x^3 + y^2 - z^2 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
 Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Mesh -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Exactly what i want, thanks!

Comment: There is only one more thing, why the axis labels are never show?

Comment: @Wyvern666 They are also there, but ugly positioned `ContourPlot3D[
 x^3 + y^2 - z^2 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
 Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Mesh -> None, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, LabelStyle -> Directive[20, Bold]]`

Comment: Ok, is ugly but not so important anyway. Thanks!